Android Room - Two databases with same name
I have an application and I've integrated room for storage.   I have a database in the app module and I have a separate module/lib for developer environment selectors.  I have a database in that module also.
However I have noticed that the database in both modules have the same name.  This is causing data integrity issues as the db for the network module was introduced in the last release.
Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number. Expected identity hash: 40e26e7134224a73639f9d83df276f33, found: a8ce1bbdb059fa47182a881598adb8ff

So data that is in the application database is not currently accessible.
e.g.
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDeveloperEnvironmentDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) :
            DeveloperEnvironmentDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            appContext,
            DeveloperEnvironmentDatabase::class.java,
            "mobile_order_database"
        ).build()
    }

and

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMobileOrderDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) :
            MobileOrderDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            appContext,
            MobileOrderDatabase::class.java,
            "mobile_order_database"
        ).build()
    }


The content in my dev environment database isn't essential and can be repopulated then next time devs/qa install the application.  Is there any to handle this scenario for my next release to allow room to provide the data stored?
any help would be greatly appreciated.  I tried to put in auto migrations in the dbs but that didn't work.  I would greatly appreciate it if someone more experienced than I in room could help

After you deleted the database file that "isn't essential" and changed your code to use another database name, what is the question that still remains?

Thank you for replying.  I didn't delete any db.  The info is essential to testing but it is repopulated when devs/qa engineers log back in.
So is your suggestion to delete the dev env db?  Any info is appreciated

Just delete the database file so that it will be recreated the next time is is needed. But make sure to change the database name in your code so it won't conflict with the other database.

Sorry, I know I'm wrecking your head but without sounding stupid, where do I locate the database file?

Just change the name for the database that "isn't essential" so that it will be recreated with its new name the next time it is needed.
On all devices that now still have the wrong "mobile_order_database" files you need to remove them by performing one of the following steps:

Uninstall the app
Clear data for the app
Manually delete the relevant database files in /data/data/<appname>/databases
Add a database migration path to "mobile_order_database" or even use .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() on the database builder to resolve the conflict. In contrast to the previous options this is not a one-off solution, you will need to support this in your app indefinitely.

Choose what is most appropriate in your situation.

Thank you but my problem is the users have the version of the app with the error.   So unless they do any of those steps, I'll still have the issue.  Is there anything that I  can do from a codebase perspective?

Added database migrations as another option. Please make sure that your question contains all relevant information from the start. That you already distributed an app version with the wrong database to the users is a completely new piece of information that would be good to know upfront. Up until now I thought this would just affect your own development environement.
